# What is the wife of a henpecked husband called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

**henpecked** [hen-pekt]
*adjective*
1. browbeaten, bullied, or intimidated by one's wife, girlfriend, etc.:
a henpecked husband who never dared to contradict his wife.

**What is the wife of a henpecked husband called? *(word or phrase)*** (in regards to her browbeating/bullying, her husband)

It might not be **henpecker** since **henpecked** seems to have the etymology of "pecked by the hen".

Sample sentence:

> That woman is a *henpecker*.

Comment: Is a single word necessary? 'henpecked husband' has two after all.

Comment: @Mitch not necessary

Comment: [vaguely related](https://www.pressreader.com/ireland/irish-independent/20180718/281818579609813)

Comment: I removed the `pejorative-language` tag. This question is not asking for single words that are pejorative. Even though some of the *answers* might be considered to be words that are pejorative, the question itself is perfectly neutral.

Comment: You tagged this single-word-requests but didn't necessarily say that. Some good answers will have multiple words. Also, are you looking for contemporary words we'd use today (in common parlance), or archaic/ literary words like 'shrew' or 'harridan', which pretty much only ever occur in writing (or recherche speech)? And why must it be a noun phrase like 'she is a nag' or 'she is a henpcker'; that's less common than 'she nags her husband' or 'she henpecks her husband'.

Comment: @smci contemporary (thanks for the idea, a "wife who henpecks" seems the best for now)

Comment: **single word or multiple word? noun-phrase or adjective or verb?**

Comment: @smci i answered Mitch above, single word "not necessary". I prefer a noun

Comment: @hazoriz... or *"a henpecking wife"*. Adjective phrase. More common than noun phrase. I suggest you drop the requirement for a noun phrase, because all you'll get is a dictionaryful of archaic words that noone uses. Or the catchall word 'b***h'.

Comment: This belongs on ESL, so we can teach you how to swear correctly. Removing the 'pejorative-language' tag was uncalled for.

Comment: @Mazura: no this question does not merit the pejorative-language tag or belong on ESL. Some answers will be archaic, some will be considered pejorative, some will not. The question is not specifically looking for a swearword.

Comment: The OP didn't add that tag; fair enough.

Comment: @hazoriz , were you aware "henpecker" is a perfectly normal word?  If you google - for example - "a real henpecker" you will find many examples of that in, eg. novels/articles.  *'that girl is going to turn into a real henpecker, I can see it coming.'* - Emma Lathen.  Hazroiz, are you simply asking for synonyms of this?  (so, "nag" is the most obvious and common).

Comment: @hazoriz , I wish you would clarify if you are looking for (A) synonyms of henpecker (so, "ball-buster, "nag" etc) or (B) you just want the noun-form of "henpecker" (so, something like "henpeckingess" or whatever).   Which is it dude?

Comment: Again though, this whole QA is a total waste of space unfortunately until OP clarifies if OP is asking for *the common noun form of a word* , or synonyms.  (Hey - aren't synonym questions banned on this site anyway?  You just glance in a synonym dictionary - every answer here is immediately listed in any synonym list.)

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: Please avoid
discussion, debate, or giving answers
in comments.
The comment thread is reserved for *helping to improve the post*: friendly clarifying questions, suggestions for improving the post,
relevant but transient information, and explanations of your actions. A welcoming place for discussion of posts (or anything else) is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: @hazoriz You have made several clarifications in comments that need to be incorporated into the question itself. Please [edit] the question to narrow it to what you are actually asking. While doing so, bear in mind the caution above, that a question should not be a request for ideas, suggestions, writing advice, etc. It should be a request for the definitive right answer to a question about the English language.

Comment: @MetaEd thank you for you advice,  (i got answer i wanted already and) i think if someone volunteers to fix the OP he will do a better job then me.

Comment: @hazoriz: But you tagged this question [tag:single-word-request], then didn't untag it; which clearly reduced the accuracy and relevance of the answers you're getting. (It was later also tagged [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/487141/3) by someone else for you.) I just edited the body to explicitly say ***(word or phrase)***. When you still said *'single word "not necessary"'* that could be interpreted as *"single word preferred but not essential"*. Just trying to help the question be clear; it's a good question.

Answer (score 121):

You might go with a word that was well-understood in the Shakespearean era:

> ***[shrew](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shrew)***
>   2: an ill-tempered scolding woman
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shrew)*</sub>

Thus the henpecked husband could say "I didn't realize it at the time but I soon discovered that I'd married a real shrew."

Answer (score 103):

You can have your pick, I like **harridan**.  But look at the synonym list, it's hysterical.

> **har·ri·dan**
> [ˈherəd(ə)n]
> NOUN
> a strict, bossy, or belligerent old woman.
> "a bullying old harridan"
>
> *synonyms*: shrew · virago · harpy · termagant · vixen · nag · hag · crone · dragon · ogress · fishwife · hellcat · she-devil · fury · gorgon · martinet · tartar · spitfire · old bag · old bat
>
> — Oxford Dictionaries ([Definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harridan) and [synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/harridan)) via [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=harridan&PC=U316&FORM=CHROMN).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90474/discussion-on-answer-by-k-dog-what-is-the-wife-of-a-henpecked-husband-called).

Answer (score 65):

The verb [*henpeck*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/henpeck) means:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : to subject (one's spouse or partner) to persistent nagging and domination

Using the common noun counterpart, you would simply say, "That woman is a [**nag**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nag)":

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> *noun*
> : one who nags habitually

Comment: If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question.

Comment: "Woe baby you're a nag (Nag nag naggity nag) ... Run down to the butcher shop and buy me a roast."

Answer (score 26):

An unambiguous colloquial phrase for this is **She Who Must Be Obeyed**. It even has a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She_Who_Must_Be_Obeyed).

The meaning of the phrase is pretty clear just from the literal words put together, but here's a source:

> *informal, depreciative*
>
> A strong-willed or domineering woman, especially a wife or female partner.
>
> <sub>-- [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/she-who-must-be-obeyed)</sub>

It may also be shortened to simply [SWMBO](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/buzzword/entries/swmbo.html).

The origin of this phrase is H. Rider Haggard's novel *She*, but there the character called "She Who Must Be Obeyed" is a fearsome and immortal queen-goddess. Its usage in popular culture to mean a henpecking wife may stem from the British TV series *Rumpole of the Bailey*, and may be mostly a Brisith English phenomenon. (Citation needed for both those last speculations, though.)

Comment: British readers will be familiar with the popular UK tv series _Rumpole of the Bailey_, a legal drama (with humourous overtones) written by former Barrister John Mortimer for ITV in the 1980s, starring Leo McKern as Horace Rumpole. This phrase, _she who must be obeyed_, was Rumpole's humorous nickname for his wife (and in origin is derived from H Rider Haggard's 1887 novel _She_).

Comment: @MetaEd That appears to be a stock comment, since I already have most of the rep-based privileges. Could you explain what you feel this answer is lacking? I've explained that (in contrast to most of the other answers here) this phrase is *unambiguous* and its meaning clear just from the simple words themselves.

Comment: I've never heard this phrase that I'm aware of, and certainly wouldn't have pegged it as synonymous with "henpecker" without specific context (I would have pegged it as describing a tyrannical queen in a fantasy story, similar to That Which Must Not Be Named or He Who Walks Behind The Rows). Is this possibly a British thing?

Comment: @MichaelS Possibly. I've edited.

Comment: This east-coast American heard this phrase a lot, decades ago, and understood it as described. But I haven't heard it any time recently.

Comment: @Randal'Thor That there are now twenty-four answers to this question. I see nothing in this answer that explains why it is the *right* answer and these other answers are wrong. Consequently, as it stands, this answer is not an answer -- it is a good idea or a suggestion, but not a definitive *answer*.

Comment: @MetaEd Do you see the words "unambiguous" or "clear" in any of the other answers? Once again, Stack Exchange is [not intended](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) to accept "one single correct answer" with all other answers being wrong - the feature of being able to post multiple answers to the same question is very much by design. I've upvoted some of the other answers, and I don't think they're all wrong, but *in my opinion* this answer is the most appropriate match for what the OP was looking for. That's why I posted it.

Comment: The male version (He who must be obeyed) would be described as a strong, assertive leader or an alpha male.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, **henpecker** is a word, feel free to use it.

There's no board of people who decide what is and isn't a word, so adding -er to an -ed word is fine, as seen in standard words like *clean-ed, clean-er*, so it makes perfect sense that *henpeck-ed* has the form *henpeck-er*.

> One who henpecks or nags.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/henpecker).

And from [Definition Of](https://www.definition-of.com/hen-pecker),

> A nagging wife

Recognised word from [Glosbe](https://glosbe.com/en/en/henpecker) and  [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-meaning-of-the-word/henpecker.html).

[Google Books results](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22henpecker%22&safe=active&ssui=on) - 'Mrs Henpecker' or 'HENPECKER' appears to be a prominent comical character in various pantomimes and plays.

[Example from *Understanding the Male Temperament*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vSataK9EMjIC&q=%22henpecker%22&dq=%22henpecker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKwbfEkN_gAhUS1-AKHanxDgQ4ChDoAQhBMAU) by Tim LaHaye:

> *I have never met a happy henpecked husband--nor, for that matter, have I met a happy **henpecker**.  You can count on this: In his frustration, a henpecked man will dedicate himself to making his **henpecker** miserable.*

*The Henpecker* is the title of a [chapter from the book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ckg_PqQmtBUC&pg=PA62&dq=%22henpecker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3ipuD-ufgAhVBTBUIHViuCk0Q6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22henpecker%22&f=false) *A Bird's Eye View of American Women*, offering a somewhat humorous outlook on the matter.

[Then Google Ngrams.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=henpecker&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chenpecker%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chenpecker%3B%2Cc1) There appears to be a spike in the '70s, FWIW.

Not forgetting [*Hen Pecker* by *The Surfdusters*](https://www.google.com/search?q=hen%20pecker%20surfdusters&rlz=1CAXWWL_enGB813GB813&oq=hen%20pecker%20surfdusters&aqs=chrome..69i57.5689j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)

See [this Yahoo Answers thread](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090202092048AA1SSOo) for further research (I know it says "hen picker", but I believe this is a mistake, as corrected by the answers.)

[image]

Comment: Do they use "henpecker" in Great Britain? I understand the meaning, but have never heard it used here in the U.S.  We do use a similar word, "nitpicker", which may be applied to either gender.

Comment: I've never heard it being used, but if you did, no-one would bat an eye.  We use *nitpicker* too, FWIW

Comment: @ScotParker Though in Britain, a *nitpicker* has no (that I know of) connotation to 'bullying' as such; it is used to describe pedantry; picking out small mistakes.

Answer (score 21):

Lots of good answers, but I'm surprised I do not see *[fishwife](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fishwife)*:

> noun
>
> A person, traditionally a woman, who persistently nags or criticizes:
>
> [*The Free Dictionary*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fishwife)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MetaEd  Oh please. StackExchange isn't designed to filter answers so only one 'right' answer remains.  In most cases, such as this one, several words, phrases, or expressions will fit the asker's criterion/a.  You have repeatedly commented on people who have _cited  sources_.  As long as the answer makes sense, is backed up by definition and cited sources, the answer is **fine**.  There is even a [Meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/henpecked-by-metaed) regarding your actions.  I **do** understand that in that case , the OP was wrong, but this has to stop.

Answer (score 18):

A **"nag"**, which literally means an old mare.

Ya, different animal than a chicken. "shrew" is seldom used in the U.S., but "nag" definitely is. Many suggestions here may be correct, but are not in common usage, so would sound weird (at least in the U.S.)

Comment: I think the worst thing you can call a woman in the English language is hackney, which is an old broken down horse, but it also means to become common, dirty and used up through over use.

Comment: Nag is used in the US but not to mean a shrew. Anyone can be a nag. Shrew only sounds weird in unschooled circles (sorry, I refuse to be PC).

Comment: @Lambie I wouldn't say it only sounds weird in unschooled circles. It sounds very weird to me, and I have a PhD.

Comment: @MattSamuel Come on, now. It's the kind of term one might use. And I fail to see how a Phd is at all relevant to this. I use "fancy" words all the time, as long as I am assured that my interlocutor(s) will understand me. I wouldn't say shrew at the convenience store down the street but I might use if at a dinner party or other gathering of my peers...

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: Nag is, as far as I am aware, the most common term for a woman who henpecks her husband. Source: half a century of life experience.

Answer (score 15):

The word often used in drama, though not so widely used today is

> a scold

Oxford Dictionaries says

> NOUN
>   US 
>   archaic 
>   A person, in particular a woman, who nags or grumbles constantly.

‘his mother was the village scold’
‘the fiscal scolds insist that reform will make everything even worse’

As you see, it is marked as archaic.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MetaEd Thank you for this. Like many, I sometimes give opinions, although I believe that ‘experience’ is allowed to be drawn on as well as research.  It is hard to prove that there is no word that fits the OP’s question, but this is as near, I think as you can get.  What exactly are you looking by way of explanation, please?

Comment: How is this answer right and the others wrong?

Answer (score 11):

**Grey mare** is an older phrase used to refer to a woman who has the final say in a marriage. Here's [an excerpt](https://www.bartleby.com/81/7636.html) from the *Dictionary of Phrase and Fable* (1898) explaining the term:

> *The Grey Mare is the better horse*. The woman is paramount. It is said that a man wished to buy a horse, but his wife took a fancy to a grey mare, and so pertinaciously insisted that the grey mare was the better horse, that the man was obliged to yield the point.

The phrase sometimes appears outside of the saying, as in this translation of Martial's [epigram 560](https://books.google.com/books?id=ssE8AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=grey%20mare%20martial&source=bl&ots=qmLQ1Kt4dT&sig=ACfU3U11W3LddQFEIdbvSiKRd6XYC-sa1g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX6dap5NzgAhVQba0KHcSFDG8Q6AEwAXoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=grey%20mare%20martial&f=false) (book X, epigram LXIX), which describes a wife with excessive control over her husband as a *grey mare*:

> You have the husband's latch-key, he has none;
>
> You are the grey mare, Polla, when all's done.

This passage in Latin [literally](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/martial/mart10.shtml) describes putting a husband in the place of a wife (translation in italics):

> Custodes das, Polla, viro, non accipis ipsa. *Polla, you give your husband guards that you don't receive yourself*
>
> Hoc est uxorem ducere, Polla, virum. *This is making your husband into a wife, Polla.*

That said, you may notice something about all of these excerpts. They come from sources that date to the start of the 20th century. **Grey mare**, rather like **henpecked husband**, is old-fashioned because of its many pejorative associations. These terms come from a sexist topos that women exerting power in a marriage is *contrary to an established order*, and a man who allows his partner to make decisions is diminished.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't approve of the history of sexism behind this term or related ones, but it does provide some interesting linguistic history.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have included explanation, context, and supporting facts. I suggest that your issue is with the question as it is phrased, and specifically its ability to lead to multiple valid answers.

Comment: Yes. Which is why I said you should first ask for clarification before answering such a question. If a question looks more like a poll or request for ideas or suggestions, please don't just post a suggestion. Help the asker to transform the question (if possible) into a question that is not a poll.

Answer (score 9):

A [**Kvetch**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kvetch), from Yiddish, has several meanings, including:

> 1 : a habitual complainer

I’ve heard Jews of an older generation use **ballbuster** to mean a henpecking wife specifically, I think as a pun on *balabusta*, Yiddish for a good homemaker.  [Merriam-Webster defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ballbuster)

> a person who is relentlessly aggressive, intimidating, or domineering

In practice, I’ve always heard it used to refer to women.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question. To comment on existing questions you can easily earn the [privilege](/privileges/comment).

Comment: @MetaEd Could you please clarify why you think either of the answers I gave, with citations, were insufficient? What additional information would you ask me to give, beyond the dictionary definition?

Comment: The objection is not about too little information, per se. It's that answers should not be ideas or suggestions. They should be attempts to definitively, once and for all, give a true and correct answer to a question about the English language. In other words, an answer should demonstrate not just that it's "a" correct answer but that it's "the" correct answer. If the problem is with the question -- if it seems so broad that it is basically a request for ideas or suggestions -- then you should first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question.

Comment: @MetaEd I honestly don’t see how my answer is any less correct than any other that lists some, but not all, synonyms. I do not understand your objection.

Comment: @Davislor - It looks to me like Ed got up on the wrong side of the biddy this morning.

Comment: @Davislor the fact that your answer is no more or less correct is the point MetaEd is making. If a question does not have a definitive answer, perhaps it's not suited to EL&U.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Then no single-word request can ever be suitable for EL&U, because English has synonyms and dialects. For example, a particular word might be used mainly by Ashkenazi Jews in New York. Certainly no request for a short phrase.

Comment: The answer in its edited (expanded) form looks good to me. // I disagree with the last sentence.  In my experience men are just as good and criticizing, complaining, moaning and groaning as women.  Perhaps you have had more opportunity to listen to men's candid descriptions of women than of women's candid descriptions of men?

Comment: @aparente001 I absolutely agree that men are every bit as capable of complaining. What I was saying was that I’ve only women get called *ballbusters*. It’s a double standard (dating from a time when society did not allow women to take care of problems that directly affected them, themselves, and forced them to get their husbands to do it, any way they could. Inevitably, there would be something very important to a wife but not her husband).

Comment: "ballbuster to mean a henpecking wife specifically, I think as a pun on balabusta" That's not what I would think it was referring to!

Answer (score 9):

Per my comments, contemporary answers are unlikely to be single words (e.g. 'shrew' is archaic/literary), and verb-phrases/adjective-phrases are more common for this than noun phrases:

- ***she is a henpecking wife***
- ***she henpecks her husband***
- ***she is a henpecker***
- ***she is a nag***
- ***nags her husband***

Here is [data from Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=henpecker%2Chenpecking+wife%2Chenpecks+her+husband%2C+she+is+a+nag%2Cnags+her+husband&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chenpecker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chenpecking%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chenpecks%20her%20husband%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshe%20is%20a%20nag%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnags%20her%20husband%3B%2Cc0) (from literature, not spoken) corroborating that; *"nags her husband"* seems to be the most common:

[image]

Comment: Great actual data, thanks.   I bet "real henpecker" sees some usage.

Comment: This is not an "effort", ***this is the "right" answer: that verb/adjective-phrases like *"She is a henpecking wife/ henpecks her husband"*** are more correct than noun-phrases**.  It does not need any editing whatsoever. I was sure what OP was looking for (unlike other respondents) because I already did ask them multiple clarifications in comments on the question. "Supporting facts" are the statistics I showed that "nags her husband" or "henpecking wife" are far more commonly used than noun-phrases like "henpecker", throughout 1861-2019.

Answer (score 7):

A somewhat more serious variant of "hen" is [biddy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/biddy):

> 1. a chicken or chick; esp., a hen
> 2. Informal a woman; esp., an elderly woman (usually old biddy) regarded contemptuously as annoying, gossipy, etc.
>
> — Collins Dictionary

I've generally taken the word, when used to refer to a fowl (not foul) female, to mean the one who "rules the roost".

This seems to be a fairly good complement of "henpecked", in both the literal and figurative senses.

Comment: Interesting. "Old biddy" was fairly common when I was growing up in northern England, but I never knew it was related to hens.

Comment: @MetaEd - I am unsure what your comment is supposed to mean.

Comment: This answer post gives "an" answer (biddy) but does not show that it's the "right" answer. Consequently the post is more of an idea or suggestion than a definitive answer.

Comment: @MetaEd - As is the case for most single word requests, there is no single "right" answer to the question.  Rather, it's normal for the OP to be given a range of suggestions to choose from.  Every now and then a given suggestion is "dead on", but that's more the exception than the rule.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly. And when a question comes up that is basically a request for ideas or suggestions, the right response is not to post a suggestion. It's to help the asker clarify the post to the point that it's narrow and clear enough that it has a "right" answer.

Comment: In the 1960's/70's "old biddy" was very common in the U.S. as well. If we had an older, mean, woman teacher that we didn't like we called her a "hag", or a "which". A little off topic though.

Comment: @ScotParker - Which did you call her?

Comment: ... All of them. "Witch" quickly went to "bitch", which seemed to be the only word the eighth grade girls used, so I started favoring it. I learned much later that the most offensive word you could call a member of the female species is "cunt". I believe it still is.

Answer (score 6):

The closest actual synonym is perhaps

## ball-breaker

(or ball-buster).

What is the sense of a henpecker?

It's a relationship where the woman "tells the man what to do" - she **usurps the (supposed) dominating, leading role of the male** by constantly telling the male what to do, by "getting the upper hand", by commanding situations.

A harridan is "any" "bossy old woman".  If you were using this archaic word, you could use it to describe any (say) bossy female politician, bossy old widow, etc.

In contrast, a henpecker (or "ball-buster") is specifically a wife who eliminates the masculinity, authority of the husband, through constant nattering.

And a shrew, if you were to use that archaic word - for me a shrew is a mean / bad-tempered / etc "independent woman" who doesn't even want to get married or have anything to do with men.

Regarding words like "nag" or "cow" ...

A vulgar synonym of "henpecked" is "pussy-whipped"; the point is the male's (supposed, whatever) usual place of authority, of decision over day to day elements in the household, has been usurped by the female. So, while a henpecker wife *may indeed be* a nag, or a cow, she may indeed just be "loud" ... but then, conversely, she may be the "silent staring" type of henpecker!  If you're really trying to describe the notion that she has "got it over" the husband - the husband is henpecked or "pussy-whipped" - about the only real synonym of "henpecker" I can think of is "ball-buster".

Or indeed perhaps simply "dominating wife" as a phrase.

Comment: It should be noted that "ball buster" is sometimes used simply to mean "odious task", and occasionally is used to refer to an unfair (and unpleasant) kick in martial arts.

Comment: It's a good point.  I'm not sure if "ball-breaker" or "ball-buster" is the usual term for *"a wife who dominates the husband"*; I've become confused thinking about it.  And I don't use such language myself, so, I don't know.

Answer (score 6):

The best answer for you depends upon which qualities of the wife you want to emphasize. If, for example, you want to keep your hole card face down, 'virago', with its superior range of senses, might be most suitable:

> **virago**, *n.*
>   ....
>   **2.**
>   **a.** A man-like, vigorous, and heroic woman; a female warrior; an amazon. Now *rare*.
>
> **3.** A bold, impudent (†or wicked) woman; a termagant, a scold.
>
> [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/223704?redirectedFrom=virago#eid) (paywalled).

Although sense **2a** is "[n]ow *rare*", that accident of usage frequency need not keep the sense from being what you intend, if pressed on the point.

The prefix 'arch-' might also be handy for your purpose:

> **arch-**, *prefix*
>   ...one who occupies a position or rank above those who bear the simple title [of 'wife' in this case]
>
> [*OED*](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/10269) (paywalled).

As the *OED* mentions, "...[s]ince the 16th cent., *arch-* has been freely prefixed to names of agents and appellatives...". So, even though 'archwife' in the sense of a

> '...wife of a superior order' (Tyrwhitt); a strong or masterful wife, a virago...
>
> op. cit.

is obsolete, the use of the prefix 'arch-', as well as its meaning, remains contemporary, and will be readily understood.

Answer (score 5):

**Shrew** is probably the best-known of many synonyms and near-synonyms, because of the Shakespeare play. An entry I have not seen in the other answers is **Xanthippe**, the name of the wife of Socrates’, alleged to have been such a woman.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question.

Answer (score 5):

Contrary to all the pejorative answers here, while a henpecked husband might be considered unusual in those cultures that share the concept, that doesn't necessarily (or even usually) imply his wife must be abnormally strong or aggressive.  Rather it'd be a case where, for whatever reasons, maybe the husband is too delicate, or too exhausted by the world, or too needy, so that their respective strengths don't balance harmoniously.

In which case the more or less normal wife would be called *"Dear"*, or *"The Mrs."*, or *"The Boss"*, *etc.*

Some pop culture examples.  [Caspar Milquetoast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspar_Milquetoast):

[image: Pollster asks Milquetoast "Are you the head of the family?"]

Harold Bissonette (W.C. Fields) from [*It's a Gift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Gift).

There's probably no point in their respective stories where either character ever much resents his 
own wife, or considers them a dragon.  However passive they seem married, they'd be no less passive single, like [Mike Judge's *Milton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milton_(cartoon)).

Comment: This answer makes the important point that the key element is, the husband has been "put under", his conventional leading, rooster-like role has been usurped.  This is why for me shrew and even harridan are not really correct.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please [edit] to include explanation, context, and supporting facts. If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, first ask for clarification in the comment box on the question.

Comment: @MetaEd, The payload of this answer is that not all such terms need be [particularly sexist or spiteful](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12041/this-is-what-we-mean-by-problems-with-the-climate).  But some questions are like [the Blind Men and the Elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_men_and_an_elephant), and this answer, like several of the answers here, is but *one* facet of a right answer.  If another picture of Milquetoast calling his wife *"dear"*, or other usage cites would help, that might be done.

Comment: In that case the problem is with the question, and the right response is not to follow the question down the garden path. The right response is to post helpful comments that lead the asker to clarify the question.

Answer (score 4):

She's a **harpy**. From [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/harpy):

> 2. countable noun
>
> If you refer to a woman as a harpy, you mean that she is very cruel or nasty.
>   [*literary*, disapproval]
>   *...a snobby, scheming harpy who sells off the family silverware.*

She is a harpy, because harpy is a term for a cruel or nasty woman.

Answer (score 3):

You could say she **"wears the trousers"** ("wears the pants" in the US).

> (especially of a woman) to be the person in a relationship who is in control and who makes decisions for both people ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wear-the-trousers))

This by extension refers to the dominant person in a relationship. It also implies the man is emasculated by metaphorically wearing a dress

*John likes to pretend he's in charge but it's Judy who really wears the trousers in that relationship.*

Answer (score 3):

A word that sprung to mind is:

> a battle-axe

From [Collin's dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/battle-axe)

> 1. countable noun
>
> If you call a middle-aged or older woman a battle-axe, you mean she is
> very difficult and unpleasant because of her fierce and determined
> attitude.
>
> [informal, disapproval]
> Synonyms: harridan, witch, fury, nag